# iOS: Connecting to BLE device when 20+ such devices are in the room?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an iOS app that connects to a certain type of BLE device, but I'm writing the code in a room that has 20+ such devices sitting around, powered up. I consistently find that in the morning, I can connect to my personal device just fine, but as the day wears on, it becomes impossible to connect to my device, as if the 20+ other devices have woken up somehow and are blocking my signal. No one is using most of these devices; they're just sitting on tables. Is this a known bug? Is Apple working on it?

Answer (score 0):

Are all the devices Advertising?
If they are advertising with say 20ms then it could be difficult to hear all. There are "only" 3 advertising channels to share between all devices. The connection happens on the same channels (the peripheral listens after it's own advertising to hear if someone want to connect).

It has nothing to do with Apple CoreBluetooth. In my experience CoreBluetooth can handle around 20 devices after connection has succeeded and the activity has moved to the traffic channels.

1) Try using a slower advertising interval. This should work okay if your app is in the foreground.
2) Use a BLE sniffer (TI USB dongle is fine) and see if connections fail on protocol level, then it is not CoreBluetooth's fault.
3) Only advertise with fast interval when needed or you really really need a fast discovery.

As a rule of thumb apple needs up to 55 advertisements in background mode to see a device when it's the only one visible. So if you really need around 1.1second discovery then you might need 20ms advertisement interval, else use 100ms or even more (see Apple advertising interval guidelines for the exact number that will optimise discovery)
100ms gives so much more capacity and not too bad discovery.
1-2s gives a much longer battery lifetime and will be found in 1-2 minutes if your app is in the background. This would be quite fine for eyeBeacons in malls or the like while you might want 100-200ms in smaller areas.